# Building OpenCV: can't get Python wrapper

Tags: python, windows, opencv, cmake

I'm trying to compile OpenCV and get its Python3 wrappers working. Python is installed and working correctly on my computer under `.../AppData/Local/Programs/Python`, but when I build the cmake project for VS2017, python3 module is listed as an unavailable module:

```
OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 ...
--     Disabled:                    js world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:          ...    python2 python3 ...
```

This is the cmake log for the building, this is the Python configurations that the script output:

```
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 .../AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/python.exe (ver 3.6.1)
--     Libraries:                   NO
--     numpy:                       .../AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.13.3)
--     packages path:               .../AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/Lib/site-packages
--
--   Python (for build):            .../AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/python.exe
--     Pylint:                      .../AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/Scripts/pylint.exe (ver: 1.7.1, checks: 111)
```

As you can see, the script can't find python libraries, I already tried passing a lot of python3 variables to the cmake script, for example:

```
cmake -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES=../opencv_contrib/modules \
-D PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR=...\Python\Python36-32\include \
-D PYTHON3_LIBRARY=...\Python\Python36-32\libs\python36.lib ../
```

I also tried:

```
-D PYTHON3_LIBRARIES=...\Python\Python36-32\libs\python36.lib
```

which is the variable displayed by the script:

```
  if(PYTHON3LIBS_VERSION_STRING)
status("    Libraries:"   HAVE_opencv_python3  THEN  "${PYTHON3_LIBRARIES} (ver ${PYTHON3LIBS_VERSION_STRING})"   ELSE NO)
  else()
status("    Libraries:"   HAVE_opencv_python3  THEN  "${PYTHON3_LIBRARIES}"                                      ELSE NO)
  endif()
```

The `HAVE_opencv_python3` variable inside the `status` function is always set to OFF: `HAVE_opencv_python3=OFF`, this is from `CMakeVars.txt` file, i also tried setting it to `ON` with `-D HAVE_opencv_python3=ON`, but it had no effect.